# React Testing Library waitFor not working with setTimeout

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

This is my react component (used for learning testing-library):

```
import '@babel/polyfill';
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { render, cleanup, fireEvent, waitFor, getByTestId, getByText} from "@testing-library/react";
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'

const FirstTest = () =>{
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
  const delayFunc = ()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      setCounter(counter+1)
    }, 5000)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 data-testid="h1counter">{counter}</h1>
      <button data-testid="buttonAdd" onClick={delayFunc}>+</button>
      <button
        disabled
        data-testid="buttonDown"
        onClick={()=> setCounter(counter-1)}
        >-</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and this is my test code:

```
afterEach(cleanup)
it('delay counter', async() =>{
  const { getByTestId } = render(<FirstTest />)
  fireEvent.click(getByTestId('buttonAdd'))
  await waitFor(()=> {
    expect((getByTestId("h1counter")).textContent).toBe("1")  
  })
})
```

My question is why `waitFor` doesn't seem to work because the result received : "0"?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the default timeout for `waitFor` is 1000ms, while your state change only happens 5000ms after the click event.

You could either reduce the `setTimeout` delay and/or increase `waitFor` timeout, but a better solution would be to [mock the timers using `jest.useFakeTimers()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks) during your test.